# sharedpreference Boolean is always returning false

Tags: java, android

I'm making a quiz where users can't access the quiz if they haven't studied.
The problem is that the variable value reads false so I can't open the quiz even though I've studied

this is the code to start the quiz

```
private void startQuiz() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENSI_APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean sudahBelajar = prefs.getBoolean("sudah_belajar", false);

        if (sudahBelajar) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Quiz1Activity.class));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Anda harus belajar dahulu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and this is the code to start learning

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_materisatu);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENSI_APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


        bttnBelajar = findViewById(R.id.bljr);
        bttnKuis = findViewById(R.id.kuis);

        bttnBelajar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bttnBelajar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Fragment fragment = new materisatuFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.materiSatu, fragment).commit();

                editor.putBoolean("sudah_belajar", true);

                editor.apply();
                }
        });
```

When you want to access the quiz when you have finished studying you can't. and a notification like this appears "You have to study first!"

Comment: Looks like your bool is never saved and because you set the default value of getBoolean to false it always returns false. Have you tried debugging setOnClickListener and onClick, maybe they are never called?

Comment: Did you tried editor.commit() after editor.apply(); in onClick listener?

Comment: if I change getboolean to true then the quiz can be accessed without studying.

Comment: yes I use editor.commit() after editor.apply(); in the onClick listener, because I'm using fragments for the learning part